# Android: lanzo mi app con Android Studio en el dispositivo y se muestra el icono 2 veces

Tags: android

**El momento en el cual lanzo mi app con Android Studio en mi dispositivo, se crean dos iconos del mismo app.**

Ya intenté exportar el apk e instalarla pero no dio resultado, sigue creando dos iconos de la misma aplicación.

¿Por qué sucede esta situación? No sé si se deba configurar algo en el Android Studio para ello.

Comment: Pon el AndroidManifest.xml para ver el error en concreto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revisa que únicamente una de tus Activity definidas en el `AndroidManifest.xml` debe tener el `intent-filter` definido con `action.MAIN` y `category.LAUNCHER`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```