# Icono de aplicacion en android duplicado

Tags: android

Al cargar mi aplicacion android desarrollada en android studio, a un dispositivo, 
me aparecen 2 launchers con el mismo icono y nombre, siendo que solo tendria que ser uno, no entiendo que pasa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa si no compilaste la misma App dos veces con dos IDs distintos. Cuando es la misma App no te deja tenerla dos veces, incluso si tienes instalada la App de la Play Store, cuando quieres depurar una nueva versión no te deja hasta que no borras la App actual.

Comment: es el mismo id, incluso, abro la aplicacion con un icono, y al abrirla con el otro icono, se reanuda lo que estaba haciendo al abrirla por primera vez, abren la misma aplicacion los 2 iconos

Comment: ¿Podrías revisar el `Manifest.xml`, o agregarlo a la pregunta para verlo?. Puede que tengas configurados dos launcher allí.

Comment: efectivamente, tenia 2 launcher, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde la respuesta de @jorgesys a tu pregunta? [Android: lanzo mi app con Android Studio en el dispositivo y se muestra el icono 2 veces](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35814/android-lanzo-mi-app-con-android-studio-en-el-dispositivo-y-se-muestra-el-icono)

Comment: si, muchas gracias