# Android Studio me genera 2 aplicaciones con iguales iconos

Tags: android, android-studio

Realizando este proyecto me percaté que al compilar o generar la APK, cuando se instala
Android Studio me genera 2 aplicaciones con iguales iconos, aqui les dejo mi Manifest a ver que pueden encontrar. Gracias.
Este es mi Android Manifest

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EnglishActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".From"
            android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Completo" />
        <activity android:name=".Fuentes" />
        <activity android:name=".Comparaciones" />
        <activity android:name=".Fpersonal" />
        <activity android:name=".Servicios" />
        <activity android:name=".Recursosh" />
        <activity android:name=".Morbilidad" />
        <activity android:name=".Mortalidad" />
        <activity android:name=".Datosd" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>`Android Studio me genera 2 aplicaciones con iguales iconos
```

Este es mi Android Manifest
`

Comment: Reseteando por el completo el emulador pasa lo mismo?

Comment: Hola! Puedes agregar tu archivo .gradle. Por otro lado, en algún momento del desarrollo cambiaste el bundleId? O siempre ha sido el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Una razòn es que tengas repetido el intent filter en màs de una Activity:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

[Android: lanzo mi app con Android Studio en el dispositivo y se muestra el icono 2 veces](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35814/android-lanzo-mi-app-con-android-studio-en-el-dispositivo-y-se-muestra-el-icono)

La otra razòn es que dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` hayas cambiado el `applicationId` de tu aplicaciòn :

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myapp.application'
        ...
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

Si esto fue asì, simplemente elimina ambas aplicaciones y sube nuevamente el proyecto.